# Filter values in a Python object array generically with a lambda function as a string

Tags: python, functional-programming, lambda

I'm working on a generic framework, and at some point I'm trying to filter variables in a generic manner. Take for example the following class:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

Then I have an array of objects with arbitrary `val` values:

```
arr = [X("1"), X("2"), X("2"), X("3"), X("foo"), X("5"), X("3")]
```

My goal is to have a function which takes a lambda function and a variable names **as strings** (because they are user provided), which is currently implemented as follows:

```
def process(lambda_f_str, var_str):
    # should return [1, 2, 3, 5]
    return list(set(filter(lambda x: x, map(eval(lambda_f_str), eval(var_str)))))
```

I want to be able to call this method with a given lambda function string that will return me only the unique integer values of these objects (In this example I'd expect `[1 2 3 5]`, the order doesn't matter).

I've tried something like this:

```
process("lambda x: x.val if isinstance(x.val, int) else None", "arr")
```

But this doesn't work since the integers are still passed as strings in my array (and I have no control over that, this is user-provided so I can't make any assumption).

I wanted to do the equivalent of

```
try:
    int(x)
except:
    # do something if not an int
```

But I don't think you can do that in a lambda function ... can you? At least I haven't found out how.

I'd be interested to see how I can write this lambda to do this filtering in a generic manner. I'd rather avoid changing the `process` method since this is a generic function which does other things not included in this sample code for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Can you write an `isint()` function and do `process("lambda x: x.val if isint(x.val) else None", "arr")`?

Comment: I thought about that, I'll probably have to settle with this if i don't find anything else, but initially i wanted to avoid this since my lambda strings are defined by the user who doesn't know that i defined a method called `isint`. Of course this could be part of documentation or comment to let the user know, but I wanted to know if there's a better way to do this, otherwise that's probably what I'll have to do.

Comment: Don't use variable names like that, and don't use a class like that. Just use a dict with the keys as the user input and the value as what you want to filter by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the evals?

```
f = lambda x: x.val if isinstance(x.val, int) else (int(x.val) if isinstance(x.val, basestring) and x.isdigit() else None)
```

Not 100% proof, e.g. it doesn't take `123L` which is valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
s = "lambda x: int(x.val) if x.val.isdigit( ) else None"
print process(s, "arr")
```

I get back...

[1, 2, 3, 5]

Note that the `.isdigit( )` method will fail if the numbers are given with commas or decimals.